# multiple green horizontal lines fuzz

Tags: digital

My digital camera is Olympus 760. When focusing/zooming, the digital screen seems to waver constantly, and after the shot is taken multiple green horizontal lines cover the whole image.

[image]

Comment: Are these lines in the images when viewed on another device? Or only when viewed on the camera's rear LCD screen?

Comment: @MichaelClark On my PC the same liens are seen

Answer (score 5):

It seems either the sensor or the associated electronics in your decade old Olympus Stylus 760 has gone on the fritz. It's probably time to consider another camera.